# Issue facing in navigating from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, appdelegate, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to do navigate from one viewController to another viewController by login button action. I am verifying that login credential through API.

**Normal button Action:** If button pressed,, navigate to next view controller. Both **Attempt 1 & Attempt 2** is working perfectly without any issue.

**Login verified through API** If success, navigate to second view controller. This time only I am facing below issue.

I am having, one image view and two labels on that second view controller. In Attempt 1, only viewController is displaying without labels and that QR Code image. In Attempt 2, secondViewController is loading perfectly, but, that navigation time interval is more than 40 seconds. how to solve this? kindly guide me.

My coding and output is below:

**ATTEMPT 1:**

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : verified_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("verified") as verified_VC
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

**OUTPUT - ATTEMPT 1:**

[image]

**ATTEMPT 2:**

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : verified_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("verified") as verified_VC
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
})
```

**OUTPUT - ATTEMPT 2:**

[image]

Comment: In attempt 1, inspect the view in XCode and check whether your `labels` and `imageView` are being displayed outside the visible area.
If that is the case, you just need to set constraints.

Comment: Thanks for u reply.  Then how it will work in  ATTEMT 2??? @sasquatch

Comment: In attempt 2, you are changing the root view, which might have different constraints.
Why don't you just inspect the view and see what is going on.